# Find the summation of this series :0,1,3,6,10,15,...,n

Tags: math, algebra

How can I find summation formula for the sequence :
:0,1,3,6,10,15,...,n

please take care the first element is 0 .

Comment: Math questions belong on <http://math.stackexchange.com>.

Comment: SO should only be used for programming based questions with sufficient research.  Please check out what is considered on-topic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not programming related.

Answer (score 6):

That sequence is the [Triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), also known as [A000217](http://oeis.org/A000217).

The value of entry `n` can be calculated with `f(n) = (n * (n+1)) / 2`.

As a comment pointed out, this only calculates the value of `f(n)`, not the summation of the series `0..n`. The summation can be calculated by `s(n) = n * (n+1) * (n+2) / 6` according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). These numbers are [Thetrahedral numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number), or [A000292](http://oeis.org/A000292).

```
n | f(n)            | s(n)
0 | 0 * 1 / 2 =  0  | 0 * 1 * 2 / 6 = 0
1 | 1 * 2 / 2 =  1  | 1 * 2 * 3 / 6 = 1
2 | 2 * 3 / 2 =  3  | 2 * 3 * 4 / 6 = 4
3 | 3 * 4 / 2 =  6  | 3 * 4 * 5 / 6 = 10
4 | 4 * 5 / 2 = 10  | 4 * 5 * 6 / 6 = 20
5 | 5 * 6 / 2 = 15  | 5 * 6 * 7 / 6 = 35
```

Comment: I am really want to start with zero , so what is the formula ,could you give me if possible : the steps..

Comment: ?  That's not right.  The triangular numbers are given by `T(n) = (n*(n+1))/2`, not their sum.  (I guess the OP could be confused about what "summation" is, though.)

Comment: @DSM, you're correct. That's what you get for not reading through the question correctly. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Maria You keep emphasizing that the first entry is 0.  Is it really that hard to shift the entire sequence by 1 to get the answer you want?

Answer (score 1):

The `i`th number in the sequence is `i(i-1)/2=(i^2-i)/2`.  Summing this from `1` to `n` gives `n(n+1)(2n+1)/12-n(n+1)/4=n(n+1)((2n+1)/12-3/12)=n(n+1)(2n-2)/12=n(n+1)(n-1)/6`.

But yeah, math questions belong on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `C` implementation of an algorithm that should do the trick

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; sum <= n; i++)
{
  sum = sum + (sum + i)
}
```

Comment: I do not need C code , I need a formula with n